# Azure AD Authentication in CI Pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I am trying to run API tests in my CI pipeline, I need to figure out if there is a way to authenticate users on azure without Microsoft's login UI?

I have read several articles like these: https://liupeirong.github.io/postmanAzureFunctions/

However, they all take you to Microsoft's UI for authenticating yourself. Not sure if there is a away to post data on that URL and get the code from Microsoft that I can later exchange it for Token.

FYI, the API's are hosted in enterprise servers not Azure Cloud

Answer (score 1):

You can not get the code without user interaction. You can use ROPC flow to get the token without user interation UI. But Microsoft recommends you do not use the ROPC flow, you can refer to

> Microsoft recommends you do not use the ROPC flow. In most scenarios,
>   more secure alternatives are available and recommended. This flow
>   requires a very high degree of trust in the application, and carries
>   risks which are not present in other flows. You should only use this
>   flow when other more secure flows can't be used.

**Reference:**

[Auth code grant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow)

[Resource owner password credentials grant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc)

[Client credentials grant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow)